# Difference Between Binary Trees and Tries

Tags: binary-tree, trie

I am having trouble understanding why tries have an O(1) lookup time and binary trees are O(logn).

I understand that they are basically trees. Suppose that I have a trie for the English language, containing words up to 16 characters. Lookup time is O(16) which simplifies to O(1). This is because each trie node has an array of 26 children (26 letters in the alphabet), and pulling from an array is o(1). So you just need to do 16 pulls.

Whereas for a binary tree, if you have n elements (say n is very large...the entire english alphabet), you search the middle element, then the middle of the subsection depending on whether your element is lower/higher, then the subset of that, etc etc...basically dividing by two each time to get O(log base 2 of n).

The logic for each makes sense. But I feel like I'm missing something.

What's the key difference between the two that allows tries to pull off lookup in constant time whereas binary trees need O(logn)? Couldn't you structure a binary tree to be basically a trie with 2 children only? I suppose I'm having trouble pinpointing the difference.

Comment: Strangely enough, if you limit your data set to one-letter words starting with the letter `a`, binary trees *also* become `O(1)` :-) The whole point of complexity analysis is what happens when the data set becomes *arbitrarily* large.

Comment: @paxdiablo So...basically they ARE the same big-o for the small cases that I'm thinking about, and I'm just failing to take into account extremely huge data sets, where tries will still be constrained by the 16 character length limit, but the binary tree will balloon massively due to the n?

Comment: No, not quite. For example, a sequential and a binary search of a sorted list may both have similar *runtimes* if the list is only a couple of elements long, but the *complexity of the algorithms* is not the same. The former is O(n), the latter O(logN). Complexity is a property of an algorithm, not of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a trie like a binary tree. Search for kart-trees.